# SSIS Kingswaysoft productivity kit: diff detector

Tags: sql-server, ssis, diff, kingswaysoft

I am using Diff Detector from Kingswaysoft productivity kit. I have a question about the business key. Both my inputs (old and new) are from CRM SQL server views and therefore I would like to use the primarykey (accountid) as the business key.

However, when the package runs I get this error:

[Diff Detector [187]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "System.Exception: An item with the same key has already been added. (SSIS Productivity Pack, v5.0.0.1199 - DtsDebugHost, v13.0.1601.5)System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.".

Has anyone experienced this? My understanding was that the business key is the common value between the 2 comparison subjects. I am missing something?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to reach out to us through our [Support Channel](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us)? We can send you a hotfix build which may take care of this issue.